# C# Class serialize or deserialize method cause a lot of GC

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, garbage-collection

I'm making 2d chank loading system,
so i make chank class, and seriallize or deseriallize this class into file
however, i have big problem, when i use method, seriallize or deseriallize, this method cause huge GC alloc, so, my game slow down.
so, i wonder seriallize cause GC or my code has problem, so, seriallize cause GC

i checked deseriallize cause GC

```
public int[,] chank_Collision_Getter(int x,int y)
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    TextAsset target_File = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("Base_Chank");
    byte[] file_Bytes = target_File.bytes;
    Stream file = new MemoryStream(file_Bytes);

    if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
    {
        read_Only_Chank = (ChankStruct)bf.Deserialize(file);//GC Alloc

    }

    file.Close();
    return read_Only_Chank.collision_Getter();
}
```

how can i reduce GC caused by deseriallize

Comment: You should be using ‘using’ statements

Comment: i replaced that code with, 'using' statement, but GC still occur.

Comment: Without significant amount of details this question is too broad for SO... Also I'm afraid even with exact details about your classes it will not be really useful - de-serialization allocates objects and it is unlikely to avoid GC. You will probably get significant benefit by using custom serialization that only writes data you need in fragments you are interested (i.e. it looks like code shown discards significant amount of info which is read, constructed and ignored)

Comment: Side note: "chank" is not an English word... which is strange looking since there rest of the code in the post is English...

Comment: You will need to implement your own systems, from the bottom up, starting with object pooling.  Once you have object pooling implemented for everything that can be in a chunk, next you can write your own deserializer that avoids allocating memory and constructs everything using your object pools.